# USBIP NAK packet

Tags: java, tcp, usb

I am trying to emulate a usb hid device by writing a usbip server.

I don't think it's too relevant, but the client is installed on windows 7 and my server is written in java for Android.

I get requests for device and configuration descriptors and return valid responses. Then I receive a SET_IDLE command and the client waits for ever for a reply.

I've been reading and coding for days but am unable to produce the response expected by the client. I believe it is waiting for a NAK packet, but I have no idea how that packet is formed for usbip.

Please help!

Comment: I'd be tempted to hang the real peripheral off a PC and talk to it via USBIP while sniffing packets in order to see what usually happens.  Also, if your Android device is wifi connected, beware of the wifi interface shutting down when there is not traffic, and similar problems.

Comment: The main device I'd like to emulate is an oculus rift head tracker. I don't have one to plug in. But I could try with any type of hid device. Was just hoping to avoid having to go through installing linux on a virtualbox just to sniff 1 simple little packet. I don't think there is a usbip server for windows.  Being a head tracker, there should be a constant stream of data so wifi shutting down shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: This might help you. Here is a usbip server implementation that emulates a HID mouse: http://breaking-the-system.blogspot.dk/2014/08/emulating-usb-devices-in-python-with-no.html